# Performance of concat and append in Scala List vs ListBuffer

Tags: scala

I want to understand the difference in performance in append and concat between `List` and `ListBuffer`

```
var myList = List(1, 2)
myList = myList ::: List(4, 5)
myList = myList :+ 6


var myMutableList = ListBuffer(1, 2)
myMutableList = myMutableList ++ ListBuffer(4, 5)
myMutableList += 6
```

My understanding is that

```
 myList = myList ::: List(4, 5)
```

will allocate space for a new list and iterate through the original `myList` and list to be concatenated and append all element to the new list

```
myList = myList :+ 6
```

will allocate space for a new list and iterate through the original `myList` and append the original item and the new item to the new list

```
myMutableList = myMutableList ++ ListBuffer(4, 5)
```

will, if there is enough space just append to the old list, but if there is not enough space will do the same thing as `myList = myList ::: List(4, 5)`

same with

```
myMutableList += 6
```

so `ListBuffer` is more efficient in both non indexed append and concat?

Comment: I think you shouldn't be focusing on how those methods perform the operations as it is implementation detail that may change and rely on declared performance characteristics as that's what the authors of the language committed to respect https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Comment: This site has some great metrics on performance and operations for Scala Collections: https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html

Comment: The Scala Docs also contain a great table of the general performance characteristics of collections: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html.

Comment: Between `List` and `ListBuffer` the three primary differences in performance lie on these operations (list first, then list buffer): tail (constant vs linear), append (linear vs constant), and insert (NA vs linear)

Answer (score 0):

`myList ::: List(4, 5)` will reverse `myList` and then will start prepending each element of the reversed `myList` into `List(4, 5)`. Thus, this is sharing / reusing the previous `List(4, 5)`
**Edit:** well, what I said above is what would happen if the stdlib `List` was truly immutable, but it is actually mutable *(just not visible outside of the stdlib)*. Thus, the stdlib exploits that to create a new `::` with the head of `myList` and the tail as `List(4, 5)` and then it will start modifying that tail of that new list to constantly prepend the remaining elements of `myList` - Anyways, the end result is the same complexity and the fact that `List(4, 5)` is shared; just faster!

`myList :+ 6` will indeed need to reallocate a new list from scratch and is very inefficient.

`myMutableList ++ ListBuffer(4, 5)` this is probably a bad idea since the idea of using a mutable collection is to mutate it, you probably want to do this instead:

```scala
val myMutableList = ListBuffer(1, 2)
myMutableList ++= ListBuffer(4, 5)
myMutableList += 6
```

In this case, both `++=` and `+=` are very efficient since they are just prepending to an internal `List` inside the `ListBuffer`

Comment: Running jmh on 1_048_576 sized a ++ b, for List and ListBuffer, I cannot seem to find much difference in cost. Looks like it is doing something clever with Views.

Comment: @MarioGalic because `++` in `ListBuffer` is `++` in `List`, you are not wining anything for using a mutable collection; since it will create a new copy anyways, that is why I suggest rather use `++=` to take advantage of mutability.

Comment: This is wrong. This is not how `:::` works in the Scala library. Link to source code: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala

Comment: `:::` is a prepend operator. The argument, which using this syntax is `myList` (postfix notation). The head of the prefix is inserted, then a while loop is used to insert the rest of the elements in order, to "prepend" `myList` to `List(5,6)`

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer I said that `myList` was prepended to `List(4, 5)`; so not sure what was your point - anyways, I was wrong due to the reverse since they exploit the internal mutability of `List` to avoid the reversal in a weird way.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez "I said that 'myList' was prepended to 'List(4, 5)'" no you said "`myList ::: List(4, 5)` will reverse `myList` and then will start appending each element of the reversed myList into `List(4, 5)`", THAT is why I commented. This is not an arbitrary distinction. You aren't APPENDING to `List(4,5)` that would result in `List(4, 5, 1, 2)` very very different

Comment: There is a method: `reverse_:::` that would reverse the prefix before PREpending it.

Comment: "Append" traditionally means "add after", "prepend" traditionally means "add before" swapping one for the other is NOT arbitrary. In the context of lists, this distinction is extremely important for ordered lists.

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer sure I had a typo, thanks for pointing it out; I just fixed it. Have a nice day.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez (you still have that it is reversed btw) But, thank you! You too! Keep up the knowledge sharing, you're a powerhouse :)

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer _"you still have that it is reversed btw"_ I added an edit with the clarification below :) - What I explained originally is how the implementation would look like in a truly immutable `List` - BTW, thank you for the kind words!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would like to address this (IMHO) totally misleading syntax

```scala
myNewList: List[Int] = myList ::: List(4, 5)
```

From the Scala Doc:

```scala
/**
* Adds the elements of a given list in front of this list.
* @param prefix The list elements to prepend.
* @tparam B Type of elements in the prefix (a subtype or equal type to A)
* @tparam A Type of elements in the suffix
* @return a list resulting from the concatenation of the given list prefix and this list.
*/
def:::[B >: A](prefix: List[B]): List[B]
```

To clarify this syntax, here is an example of what this would look like with postfix notation (as you have) as compared to normal infix notation (apply a function to an object)

```scala
// Postfix on left, equivalent to infix on right
List(1, 2) ::: List(3, 4) = List(3, 4).:::(List(1, 2)) = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

What you are really writing above is this:

```scala
myNewList: List[Int] = List(4, 5).:::(myList)
```

Semantically, append is what it appears to do, but with infix notation, we see the prefix is the argument to this function, not the suffix.

As to the performance of `concat` both list and listbuffer have the same signature:

```scala
final def concat[B >: A](suffix: IterableOnce[B]): List[B] // Or ListBuffer[B] for `ListBuffer`
```

Thus concat is likely implemented using the append operations of their respective types, for `List`s, this is linear; For a `ListBuffer`, this is constant. For small lists/buffers, however, this difference is likely arbitrary.